# INSERT en SQLSERVER con DELPHI XE4

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

Soy nuevo en Delphi XE4 y no encuentro donde esta mi error en la consulta:

```
INSERT into CUENTAS (codigocu,nombre,apellido,idcondiva,email) values ( :icodigocu, :inombre, :iapellido, :iidcondiva, :iemail);
```

El error que me muestra es este:

```
dbexpress driver does not support the tdbxtypes.unknown data type.Vendor error message
```

Se que hay un error en los parametros de la consulta, pero no lo estoy encontrando. Soy nuevo en Delphi.

Script:

```
unit UServerMethods;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Data.DBXMSSQL, Data.FMTBcd, Data.DB,
  Data.SqlExpr;

type
  {$METHODINFO ON}
  TTServerMethods = class(TDataModule)
    DBEMPRESA: TSQLConnection;
    SQLDataSetInsertCuenta: TSQLDataSet;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function setCuenta(var icodigocu: integer; var inombre: string; var iapellido: string;var iicondiva:string; var iemail: string):String;
  end;
   {$METHODINFO OFF}
   //falta crear funciones para cada modelo
var
  TServerMethods: TTServerMethods;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}
function TTServerMethods.setCuenta(var icodigocu: integer; var inombre: string; var iapellido: string;var iicondiva:string; var iemail: string):String;
begin

end;
end.
```

Script de DBX:

```
object TServerMethods: TTServerMethods
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Height = 252
  Width = 379
  object DBEMPRESA: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'DBEMPRESA'
    DriverName = 'MSSQL'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverName=MSSQL'
      'SchemaOverride=%.dbo'
      'DriverUnit=Data.DBXMSSQL'

        'DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver180.' +
        'bpl'

        'DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borla' +
        'nd.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=18.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicK' +
        'eyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'

        'MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDr' +
        'iver180.bpl'

        'MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFact' +
        'ory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=18.0.0.0,Culture=neutral' +
        ',PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'
      'LibraryName=dbxmss.dll'
      'VendorLib=sqlncli10.dll'
      'VendorLibWin64=sqlncli10.dll'
      'HostName=DESKTOP-KPIEO6C\SQLEXPRESS'
      'Database=DBEMPRESA'
      'MaxBlobSize=-1'
      'LocaleCode=0000'
      'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
      'OSAuthentication=False'
      'PrepareSQL=True'
      'User_Name=JDario'
      'Password=qwertya'
      'BlobSize=-1'
      'ErrorResourceFile='
      'OS Authentication=False'
      'Prepare SQL=False')
    Connected = True
    Left = 40
    Top = 29
  end
  object SQLDataSetInsertCuenta: TSQLDataSet
    SchemaName = 'JDario'
    CommandText = 
      'INSERT into CUENTAS (codigocu,nombre,apellido,idcondiva,email)va' +
      'lues (:icodigocu,:inombre,:iapellido,:iidcondiva,:iemail);'
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <
      item
        DataType = ftUnknown
        Name = 'icodigocu'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftUnknown
        Name = 'inombre'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftUnknown
        Name = 'iapellido'#39
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftUnknown
        Name = 'iidcondiva'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end
      item
        DataType = ftUnknown
        Name = 'iemail'
        ParamType = ptInput
      end>
    SQLConnection = DBEMPRESA
    Left = 232
    Top = 32
  end
end
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo que estas escribiendo en delphi, el error pareceria implicar que esta ahi, en la forma en la que mandas los parametros

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por responder, esta es la otra parte del código.

Comment: ¿dónde ejecutas o cómo llamas a SQLDataSetInsertCuenta? A primera vista diría que el error está en que no asignas todos los parámetros. Lo cuál podrías sortear asignando el tipo de dato de cada parámetro en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: el tema es que cada parámetro también debe de tener un tipo de dato, entero, cadena, fecha (Integer, string, Date) etc.

Comment: Asegurate que has asignado el valor del tipo correcto a cada paràmetro del Query de la sentencia de inserción. OJO!!! La sentencia puede ser incorrecta, debe haber un espacio entre ) y values. Y....que es #39 en el nombre del parámetro iapellido?